# How to darken selected text of `textEdit.find()` in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, highlight, qtextedit

I have this method that finds a term in a textEdit:

```
def search(self, term, case_sensitive=False):
    self.textedit.moveCursor(qtg.QTextCursor.Start)
    if case_sensitive:
        cur = self.textedit.find(
            term,
            qtg.QTextDocument.FindCaseSensitively
        )
    else:
        cur = self.textedit.find(term)
    if not cur:
        self.statusBar().showMessage('No matches Found', 2000)
```

Now the function is working properly but the `textedit.find(term)` seems to just lightly highlight the found text like this

[image]

My question is if `textedit.find(term)` can select the found text like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the color associated with QPalette::Highlight:

```py
p = self.textedit.palette()
p.setColor(qtg.QPalette.Highlight, QColor("blue"))
self.textedit.setPalette(p)
```

Comment: I believe that it should also be pointed that the problem is related to the focus (in the second image the cursor is indeed visible), so a `setFocus()` could be done on the text edit when the search is successful; also, for consistency, the default highlight color should be used for the palette, so that it automatically overrides the other color groups without using "another" (although possibly similar) color.

Comment: @eyllanesc, @musicamante - Thak You! The thing I need is `setFocus()`. I add that when the search is successful, the selected item is just like the 2nd picture. I also tried changing the color associated to the highlight and it also worked. Thank you to both of you.

Comment: @Amaterasu you're very welcome. Note that you should consider if the search button should actually have a focus policy: a good implementation would use `searchButton.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)` since it would lose the focus anyway, and then use a QAction with a global QShortcut (such as the commonly used ctrl+f) to trigger the search, if the search field (or an already active search query) exists, it will *continue* the search, otherwise it will display the search box.

Comment: Thank you! That was surely a better implementation than what I have right now and I will surely try that. Once again, I'm very thankful for your suggestion.